# Handling associative array and foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to write a generic function for my mailing system.

What I'm planning to do is.

1. Get all the to-address values in an array and the required information
2. Store all the values in the database.

I started with two dimensional associate array, but I'm not able to retrieve the values in the foreach.

Finally the foreach echo statement should be like

```
insert into my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') values ('Author1','author1@gmail.com','Subject','Message','test@gmail.com');
insert into my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') values ('Author2','author2@gmail.com','Subject','Message','test@gmail.com');
insert into my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') values ('Author3','author3@gmail.com','Subject','Message','test@gmail.com');
```

Here below is my code, I know the problem is with the foreach loop. I would be happy even if the associate array is minimized without the numeric sequence lik [0],[1],[2].

```
<?php
$to_address = array(
    array( 'Name' => "Author1", 'Email' => 'author1@gmail.com' ),
    array( 'Name' => "Author2",  'Email' => 'author2@gmail.com' ),
    array( 'Name' => "Author3", 'Email' => 'author3@gmail.com')
);

$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
$add_cc  = "test@gmail.com";
sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc);

function sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc) {
    foreach ($to_address as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $key1 => $val1) {
            print_r($val1);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks,
Kimz

EDIT:

In other words, I'm not able to loop the $to_address value and I need a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you want  - 
This will create the Insert queries you require.

```
<?php
$to_address = array( array( 'Name' => "Author1", 'Email' => 'author1@gmail.com' ),
array( 'Name' => "Author2",  'Email' => 'author2@gmail.com' ),
array( 'Name' => "Author3", 'Email' => 'author3@gmail.com')
);
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
$add_cc  = "test@gmail.com";
sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc);

function sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc){

    foreach ($to_address as $key => $val) {
        $sqlStatement =  "INSERT INTO my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') VALUES ('".$val['Name']."','".$val['Email']."','".$subject."','".$message ."','".$add_cc."');";
        echo "$sqlStatement <br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you want it? You can just use a single foreach and put each array in the `INSERT`.

```
    $to_address = array(
        array( 'Name' => "Author1", 'Email' => 'author1@gmail.com' ),
        array( 'Name' => "Author2",  'Email' => 'author2@gmail.com' ),
        array( 'Name' => "Author3", 'Email' => 'author3@gmail.com')
    );

    $subject = "Subject";
    $message = "Message";
    $add_cc  = "test@gmail.com";
    sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc);

function sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc) {
          foreach ($to_address as $val) {
              $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') 
                      VALUES ('".$val['Name']."','".$val['Email']."','".$subject."','".$message ."','".$add_cc."');";
              echo $sql . "<br>";
              //Use your Insert Statement
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the values in a single foreach:

```
function sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc){

    foreach ($to_address as $val) {
       $name = $val["Name"];
       $email = $val["Email"];
       echo "Name: $name, Email: $email <br\>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks first

- Use names that tell me what is inside a variable. thinngs like $val => $key tell me nothing.
  neither do `foreach ( $val as $key1 => $val1 )`
- indentation: use it, and look at psr-*
- again, describe what is happening. a function sendMail should send an email. Not print a query

### The solution

```
$mailReceivers = array(
    array( 'Name' => "Author1", 'Email' => 'author1@gmail.com' ),
    array( 'Name' => "Author2",  'Email' => 'author2@gmail.com' ),
    array( 'Name' => "Author3", 'Email' => 'author3@gmail.com')
);

$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
$add_cc  = "test@gmail.com";

foreach ( $mailReceivers as $receiver )
{
    parseMail($reciever['Name'], $reciever['Email'], $subject, $message, $add_cc);
}

function parseMail($name, $email, $subject, $message, $cc)
{
    print 'INSERT INTO my_table ('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') VALUES ('. $name .', '. $email .', '. $subject .', '. $message .', '. $subject .')';
}
```

#### Remarks

I called the function parseMail since I do'nt think you want to print an insert statement. Call it what you want it to be.

You also seem to not know how foreach works. Play a little with it and see what the `$key => $val` thing meens.

I also moved the foreach out of the function.this makes it more portable and is easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

foreach ($to_address as $val) {

$sql = "insert into my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') values (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $val['Name'], $val['Email'], $subject, $message, $add_cc);
);

mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   function sendMail($to_address,$subject,$message,$add_cc){

            foreach ($to_address as $key => $val) {

               extract($val);
               // use the keys of $val array as variable names 
               // http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

               // sql for data base query
               $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table('name','to_address','subject','message','add_cc') VALUES ('".$Name."','".$Email."','".$subject."','".$message ."','".$add_cc."');";

               echo $sql;
            }
        }
```

Comment: whats wrong with a simple array access? you only need the name and to_addreS. all you know the array could have tons of keys

Comment: nothing , i just like to use extract as the code becomes more readable and the variables becomes self-explanatory. And yes it would become tedious to use with array with tons of keys